# Get all pieces from string, when it begins with @

Tags: php, regex

I need get all matches in string, when word begins with  `@` and then contains only alnym `0-9a-z` characters. for example from this string `@ww@ee  x@@vx @ss @aa assadd @sfsd` I need get these pieces:

`@ss`
`@aa`
`@sfsd`

I am trying:

```
    $str = "@ww@ee  x@@vx @ss @aa assadd @sfsd";
    preg_match_all("#(^|\s)\@([0-9a-z]+)(\s+|$)#ui", $str, $matches);
    var_dump( $matches );
```

But this gives only `@ss`
`@sfsd` and skips `@aa`.

What would be right pattern for this?

Comment: I think you just need [`'~\B(?<!@)@([0-9a-z]+)(?:\s|$)~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/wN3wA1/1).

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/jkgfCy)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post this as an answer with details of how this works. That will be great help.

Comment: Ok, let me post with explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
'~\B(?<!@)@([0-9a-z]+)(?:\s|$)~iu'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN3wA1/1) and here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/jkgfCy):

```
$re = '~\B(?<!@)@([0-9a-z]+)(?:\s|$)~ui'; 
$str = "@ww@ee  x@@vx @ss @aa assadd @sfsd"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The regex explanation:

- `\B` - match the non-word boundary location (that is, everywhere but between `^` and `\w`, `\w` and `$`, `\W` and `\w`, `\w` and `\W)`)
- `(?<!@)` - fail the match if there is a `@` before the current location
- `@` - a `@` symbol (does not have to be escaped)
- `([0-9a-z]+)` - Group 1 (since the `(...)` are not escaped, they capture a subpattern and store it in a special memory slot)
- `(?:\s|$)` - a non-capturing group (only meant to group alternatives) matching a whitespace (`\s`) or `$`.

The `~ui` modifiers allow proper handling of Unicode strings (`u`) and make the pattern case insensitive (`i`).

Note that `\B` is forcing a non-word character to appear before `@`. But you do not want to match if another `@` precedes the `@wwww`-like string. Thus, we have to use the negative lookbehind `(?<!@)` that restricts the matches even further.